# Determining if a number is above or below another number

Tags: computer-algebra-systems, programming

I want to know if there is a way, using Excel or a similar program, because I have a bit too many numbers to do it by hand, to determin if any given number $x$ is above or below a set number $b$.

Is $x>b$ or $x<b$?

So given a set number 10 I want a fast way to check if a number 15 is above or below 10. Here the result is above.

Comment: Pretty much every computer program will have some method of comparing values. If you want to use excel, try googling "excel if greater than"

Comment: What @erfink said.  This is going to depend primarily on what kind of primitives there are in whatever application you're processing your data in.

Answer (score 1):

To test if cell A1 is bigger than $10$, type

=IF(A1>10,1,0)

return $1$ if greater than $10$, otherwise $0$.